# Moving menus in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I make my own theme for wordpress, but the problem is that i can't move pages from vertical menu to horizontal menu. So how can I move pages from vertical menu to horizontal menu in wordpress, Like this image?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/852/questionq.gif/

Comment: Depends on how your theme is built. Do you have the 2 menus appearing in your admin?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of horizontal menu:

```
<div id="navmenu">
<ul>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>">HOME</a></li>
<?php wp_list_pages('orderby=name&include=1,3,4,5'); ?>
 <li><a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WORDPRESS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```